How to configure JSONPath JsonProvider with Apache CxfClient
I am configuring a CXF client to send requests and receive responses from an HTTP web service to further process but I am having issues with my JSON provider. I am getting an error "No message body writer has been found". I am not sure if I it is a compatibility issue, or an issue with how I am setting up my code. Here is how my code looks like.
Bean Config
@Configuration
public class JsonProviderConfig {

@Bean
public jsonProvider jsonProvider() {
    return new jsonProvider();
}

Creating the client (There is more but this is the base)
private CxfClientModel createResourceClientModule(Conn conn) {
    return super.createClientModel(conn)
            .builder()
            .setProviders(Arrays.asList(jsonProvider))
            .setLogging(Logging.base().builder()
                    .setLogging(true)
                    .setInInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new LoggingInInterceptor()))
                    .setOutInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new LoggingOutInterceptor()))
                    .build())
            .build();
}

Request Object (With list of Encryption Object)
 public class Request {

      @JsonProperty
      private String id;

      @JsonProperty
      private String key;

      @JsonProperty
      private String reference;

      @JsonProperty
      private final List<Encrypted> encrypted;

      public Request() {

      }
 }

Response Object (With list of Decrypted Object)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty
    private Boolean success;

    @JsonProperty
    private String reference;

    @JsonProperty
    private String messageId;

    @JsonProperty
    private List<Decrypted> decrypted;

    public Response() {

    }
}

And here is my error
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils    : No message body writer has been found for class Request, ContentType: application/json

o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for {http://connector/}Resource has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class Request, ContentType: application/json
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(ClientProxyImpl.java:1142)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient$AbstractBodyWriter.handleMessage(AbstractClient.java:1223)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:710)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:925)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:348)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy451.decrypt(Unknown Source)

I know for a fact the issue is with the provider or how I am setting my response and request class, because when I changed the provider to JacksonJaxbJsonProvider and configured the request and response with the correct annotations it worked, but I am not allowed to change my POM.XML to add the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs dependency, so I have to work with the JSONPath JsonProvider. Is it even possible, or is there an issue with me setting up my bean?
